# Sending packets from server to clients is not fast enough (code included)

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, video, udp

Im writing a video conference application in C#, and im running into some video delay problems,

The client will take images from the webcame, 10 frames per second, and will send them to the server (one by one) using TCP (which soon will be converted to UDP). I use Socket.Send and the socket is Blocking.
        `

```
if (VideoSoc != null)
{
    try
    {
        VideoSoc.SendBufferSize = picChunk.Length;
        VideoSoc.Send(picChunk);
        sendimage++;
    }
    catch (SocketException expp)
    {
        if (expp.ErrorCode == 10054)
        {
            //ConnectSockets();
            //MessageBox.Show("Video has been disconnected.");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exppp) { }
}
```

on the server There is a Room class, and a User class, each User that connects to there will have a Queue of type byte[] to store the images that was recieved by this user.

```
List<byte> bl = new List<byte>(VideoPacket.Videobuffer);
bl.RemoveRange(iRx, VideoPacket.Videobuffer.Length - iRx);
byte[] nb = new byte[bl.Count];
bl.CopyTo(nb);
Rooms[VideoPacket.Index].UsersList[VideoPacket.Pos].VideoList.Enqueue(nb);
```

Then in a While(true) loop, on a different thread than the main thread, the server will go through the users list , get the image stored in the queue and send it to all other connected clients using a udp socket.

```
while (true)
{
    try
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < Rooms[roomindex].UsersList.Count; x++)
        {
            try
            {
                // this is my temp solution to eliminate the delay.. if more than 10 frames are stacked up in the ques.. clear them, which will effect the smoothness of the video on the client side
                if (Rooms[roomindex].UsersList[x].VideoList.Count >10)
                {
                    Rooms[roomindex].UsersList[x].VideoList.Clear();
                }
                countt = Rooms[roomindex].UsersList[x].VideoList.Count;

                if (Rooms[roomindex].UsersList[x].VideoList.Count > 0)
                {
                    byte[] videodata = Rooms[roomindex].UsersList[x].VideoList.Dequeue();

                    for (int i = 0; i < Rooms[roomindex].UsersList.Count; i++)
                    {
                        if (i != x && Rooms[roomindex].UsersList[i].Username != "u" && Rooms[roomindex].UsersList[i].Ready)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                Rooms[roomindex].UsersList[i].udpvideosocket.SendTo(videodata, Rooms[roomindex].UsersList[i].ep);
                            }
                            catch(Exception ex) { }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exo)
            {
                Rooms[roomindex].UsersList[x].VideoList.Clear();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception VideoSendingException)
    {
         logerror(VideoSendingException);
    }
```

Here i can see that each user video queue count is increasing when more and more when new clients connect, which drived the conclusion that the upd socket.send is not fast enough to send the data to 20 connected clients. and that is my problem.

I am not an expert on sockets, i did my best with the knowlde google search results has to offer a biggener. and i know my code is not the best, and its not optimized, so any advice or pointing in the right direction is welcomed.
Please feel free to ask for any clarification.

## Thank you.

because of the difficulties UDP faces when its behind NAT routers, im back to using TCP.

Comment: I think you should spend more time in the debugger and less time on google/SO. :)

Comment: Are you trying to send simultaneous video to 20 connected clients? I.e. each client sees all 19 remote videos at the same time.

Comment: so you dont see any fundimental issues with the code?? it just needs tuning, or is the a completely different (better) way to it!

Comment: @Marc yes, actaully more than 20, but becuase of this problem, 20 is the max right now

Comment: go ahead and profile your app. at a first glance, I don't see anything asynchronous, which is definitely wrong for such solution

Comment: I'm pretty sure you'll run into bandwidth issues *very* quickly. Video is quite large, and once you bring in Audio.... Top-end video conferencing systems today cannot do this and they're using specific hardware to compress the daylights out of everything.

Comment: @driushkin, actually all the socket im using are asynchronous (blocking) sockets.

Comment: @Marc each client will be sending ~4.5Kbps * 20 = 90Kbps recieved on the server
90kps * 19 (clients) = 1710 KBps out from the server. 
i have a dedicated server with 100Mbps speed, and 3000GB monthly bandwidth

Answer (score 1):

From MSDN [Socket.SendTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eae4f5y0.aspx):

`If you are using a connectionless protocol in blocking mode, SendTo will block until the datagram is sent.`

As I understand, this is exactly what you are doing.

Comment: Im very confused about this Blocking, non-blocking, asynchronous, synchronous terms.

As i understand, if i use a udp socket, it will be better because then the cpu will not wait for the network card to return an ackn that the packet was successfully sent,

now a blocking udp means that the socket will wait untill all the data that was provided to the sendTo comman is Sent. 

while none blocking, will not wait, and will send the next data regardless if the previous one is completely sent or not. and i dont want that. 

so am i right to use udp blocking socket with SendTo comman?

Comment: ok, I may be wrong that `SendTo` is your bottleneck; i must admit, I'm no expert in UDP. But that exception swallowing seems suspicious to me, you should check if that happens often. Also, you can profile your network, maybe it is indeed bandwidth problem.

Comment: I have breakpoints on those catches and they are rarely hit, thats why i just dicarded them.

Another question, will this work on internet?! if 2 clients are connected to the server from behind the same router. will the udp know its way around?